# Разбиение Stream<String>

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть `Stream<String>`, как разбить его на несколько Stream или List, относительно тех строк, которые начинаются с определенного слова (аналогично `split("word")` на обычной строке)?

Например, для "word":

```
[word, hello, dude, word and word2, stackoverflow, question, ask, word, example]
=>
[[hello, dude], [stackoverflow, question, ask], [example]]

(Stream<String> => Stream<Stream<String>>)
```

Comment: создать собственную реализацию интерфейса Collector

Comment: @velial можно метод для перебора коллекции сделать 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно собрать в Map по группам (группа -> список слов), а затем развернуть значения. Пример:

```
Stream<String> src = Stream.of("word", "hello", "dude", "word and word2", "stackoverflow", "question", "ask", "word", "example");
final AtomicInteger group = new AtomicInteger(0);
Stream<Stream<String>> streamResult = src.map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, s.startsWith("word") ? 0 * group.incrementAndGet() - 1 : group.get()))
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > -1)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
        .values().stream().map(List::stream);
```

Если нужен результат в виде `List<List<String>>` то:

```
List<List<String>> listResult = new ArrayList<>(src.map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, s.startsWith("word") ? 0 * group.incrementAndGet() - 1 : group.get()))
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > -1)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
        .values());
```

Хотя в вашей ситуации непонятно зачем использовать именно stream-ы - проще просто проитерироваться по коллекции и собрать результат в нужном виде.

Comment: Основная смысл оставаться на stream-ах был в том, что преобразования до и после делаются именно на них, но похоже в данном случае преобразования без них более читаемы и понятны.
Правильно я понимаю, что если части строк после "word" уникальны, то можно немного упростив Ваш первый код получить Map<String, List<String>>?

Comment: А что будет в качестве ключа?

Comment: Строка, начинающаяся с "word" или substring от нее.

Comment: В таком случае получить Map<String, List<String>> из приведенного мною кода, "немного упростив", врядли получится. Тут как раз вариант без stream-ов хорошо решит задачу.

Comment: Красивое решение! Правда, работает корректно только в однопоточных Stream, распараллеливать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж отметился в комментах, то приведу свою реализацию через [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).
Кстати, данная реализация будет корректно работать и в случае распараллеливания [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public final class StringSequenceSplitter
{
    private StringSequenceSplitter() { }

    private static class Accum
    {
        private final List<String> buffered = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        private final Function<String,Boolean> split_detector;
        private final boolean exclude_splitter;

        public Accum(Function<String,Boolean> split_detector, boolean exclude_splitter)
        {
            this.split_detector = split_detector;
            this.exclude_splitter = exclude_splitter;
        }

        public Accum pushElement(String element)
        {
            boolean new_seq = split_detector.apply(element);

            if ( new_seq )
            {
                List<String> new_list = new ArrayList<>();
                if ( ! exclude_splitter )
                    new_list.add(element);
                data.add(new_list);
            }
            else if ( data.size() > 0 )
                data.get(data.size() - 1).add(element);
            else
                buffered.add(element);

            return this;
        }

        public static Accum combine(Accum a1, Accum a2)
        {
            if ( a1.data.size() > 0 )
            {
                a1.data.get(a1.data.size() - 1).addAll(a2.buffered);
                a1.data.addAll(a2.data);
            }
            else
            {
                a1.buffered.addAll(a2.buffered);
                a1.data.addAll(a2.data);
            }

            return a1;
        }

        public List<List<String>> getResults()
        {
            if ( buffered.size() > 0 )
                data.add(0, buffered);

            return data;
        }
    }

    public static Collector<String, ?, List<List<String>>> of(String splitter, boolean excludeSplitter, boolean ignoreCase)
    {
        Function<String, Boolean> split_detector =
            ignoreCase ?
            s -> (s.length() >= splitter.length()) && s.substring(0, splitter.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(splitter) :
            s -> s.startsWith(splitter);

        return Collector.of
        (
            () -> new Accum(split_detector, excludeSplitter),
            Accum::pushElement,
            Accum::combine,
            Accum::getResults
        );
    }
}
```

Данная реализация [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) возвращает `List<List<String>>`, но переделать под `Stream<Stream<String>>` - дело несложное.
Пример использования:

```
Stream.of("word", "hello", "dude", "word and word2", "stackoverflow", "question", "ask", "word", "example")
    .parallel()  // для демонстрации работы с параллельными Stream
    .collect(StringSequenceSplitter.of("word", true, false))
    .forEach(list -> System.out.println("  " + list.toString()));
```

Напоследок, хотелось бы предостеречь автора от неосторожного использования вложенных объектов [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).
`Stream` - объект одноразовый, в том смысле что получить данные из него можно только однажды. Если потребуется повторно запросить данные, то нужно *создавать* новый объект `Stream` (а для этого надо иметь в наличии исходный массив или коллекцию, от которой получали `Stream`).
Для иллюстрации "одноразовости" объектов `Stream` приведу следующий код.
(даёт ошибку в 3-й строке)

```
Stream.of(Stream.of("1", "2"), Stream.of("1", "2", "3"))
    .filter(stream -> stream.count() > 2)
    .forEach(stream -> System.out.println(stream.findFirst().orElse("-")));
```

P.S.:
Приведённую реализацию [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) можно обобщить на любой тип данных.
Обобщённую реализацию и примеры использования можно глянуть [здесь](https://github.com/yizraor/SequenceSplitCollector).